# C++ on Ubuntu 12.04 gcc 4.8.1 gdb 7.6.1. I still get gdb error: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function

Tags: gcc, gdb

I am developing C++ applications on Ubuntu 12.04 using Qt Creator 2.8.1 IDE. I've recently installed gcc 4.8.1 and gdb 7.6.1 - both are the latest. Since I installed new gcc 4.8.1 I started getting this error message from gdb, upgrading gdb to the latest 7.6.1 did not solve the problem.

To be more specific: when I run gdb 7.6.1 from the command line I do not get the error message. When I run gdb 7.6.1 from the Qt Creator environment I do not get the message when I debug "old" apps that I added to Qt Creator before installing gcc 4.8.1. And I do get the error message when I run gdb 7.6.1 from the Qt Creator environment when I debug "new" apps that I added after installing new gcc 4.8.1.

This sounds like a problem with Qt Creator which pulls environment variables from the system. Unfortunately no one answers my question on Qt Creator forums. The closest solution I found is in this blog however I do not understand what the author means by "you can point gdb to the *copy filesystem*". 
http://www.fayewilliams.com/2013/01/31/gdb-unable-to-find-dynamic-linker-breakpoint-function/

Edit: I believe I have only one version of gcc and one version of gdb installed.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

P.S. Here is the error message:
Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.Could not load shared library symbols for 5 libraries, e.g. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [post you reference](http://www.fayewilliams.com/2013/01/31/gdb-unable-to-find-dynamic-linker-breakpoint-function/) discusses the issue you describe when doing remote debugging (mostly on embedded systems). I've encountered the issue myself and sorted it as described below.

In QtCreator, go to **Options** -> **Build & Run** -> **Kits**, select the kit you are using and fill the **sysroot** value.

[image]

In my case I needed to point my remote debugger to a local copy of my target file system. If you are debugging locally on your desktop, the issue is more perplexing, you could try just setting it to **/**.